# How can I model a "weapon overheating" mechanic?

Tags: gui, logic, first-person-shooter

I want to create a weapon overheating system very similar to the plasma rifle in Halo. You can [watch a video of the plasma rifle firing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lionK0JtHsc#t=29).

What I want to do is to create a flexible logic that can be used for multiple weapons for different in-game feelings.  Here is my proposed system

1. Create a bar that is split from 0 - 100.
2. Each bullet has a heat value as an integer.
3. Every bullet adds this value to the bar.
4. The bar has a cooldown set as some value per second.
5. If the bar goes over 100 with any bullet fire the bullet still shoots but then the weapon is deactivated for a period defined as it's "cooldown."

Now this system is very simple but visually it will be very linear, with a simple growth and decay. I wanted to try to create a more exponential system that would mean the bar would jump quickly to the middle then remain and hover near the top / hot bit of the bar for a long period to create a sense of anticipation just before it overheats.

What would be a good formula to achieve that result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the gun heat up quickly but reach its overheat threshold slowly, you could take the gun's current temperature into account in the heat dissipation, rather than having a constant rate of heat dispersion. That's actually how it works in the real world: the rate of heat / thermal transfer is proportional to the difference in temperature. Wikipedia has a good article on [Heat Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer) that covers this.

I strongly recommend a decimal value instead of int for tracking heat on your weapons, and to not have a strict cap so much as a threshold over which the weapon goes into cooldown to prevent damage from overheating.

A heat transfer rate equation might be helpful.

```
Rate = k•(T1 - T2)/m
Where k is the heat transfer coefficient of the gun's material.
    Since you're not modelling a specific
T1 is temperature of the world around the gun
T2 is temperature of the gun
m is mass.
```

You can probably implement this for your game as

```
void cooldown(double timeElapsed) {
    gunHeat -= timeElapsed * COOLING_RATE * gunHeat;
}
```

Where gunHeat is how much hotter than the surrounding air your gun is, aka your heat variable; COOLING_RATE is a constant value for the gun according to its materials and how good it is at keeping itself cool; and timeElapsed is the fraction of a second of the game world that has been simulated since `cooldown()` was last called. Then you just add a constant value to gunHeat whenever the gun fires.

An improved version could take into account the temperature of the environment around the player:

```
void cooldownBetter(double timeElapsed, double localTemperature) {
    gunTemperature += timeElapsed * COOLING_RATE * (localTemperature - gunTemperature);
}
```

In either case, when the gun's heat/temperature is above a certain threshold, it stops shooting until the heat drops below a threshold. This could be the same threshold, so that shooting would effectively just slow down, or a lower heat/temperature so that you have to wait but then begin shooting again as fast as before.

You'll have to test and tweak COOLING_RATE to match what you want to go for for each gun.

Comment: Yes I like trying to represent it like the real world a lot.  I shall set specific cooling rates for each weapon and test the feel for each to create variety.

Comment: Kinnth, try not to forget that when it comes to games: if it looks like the real thing and it works, it works. Don't try to model everything after the real world, imo it's a waste. Sean Middleditch solution works great as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your weapon needs two values: the current `heat` value (int, probably) and a `cooldown` timer (float).  Initialize both to `0`.

When a shot is fired, add the bullet's `heat` value to the gun's.  Cap it at `100`.  When this value reaches `100`, set the `cooldown` value to your cooldown period time in seconds.  Reduce this by your time delta every frame, clamped at a minimum to `0`.  Don't let the gun fire shots if `cooldown` is not `0`.

In pseudocode:

```
Gun.fire(bullet):
  this.cooldown = max(this.cooldown - game.time_delta, 0)

  if this.cooldown == 0:
    create_and_fire_bullet_instance(this.muzzle.transform, bullet)

    this.heat = min(this.heat + bullet.heat, 100)
    if this.heat == 100:
      this.cooldown = 3 seconds
```

Comment: if this.heat >= 100: this.cooldown = 100 ( capping it)

Comment: Bah I meant, heat = 100. Unless you just go with cooldown.

Comment: `heat` cannot be >=100 in the code I posted due to the call to `min` right above it.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Eh, no you're right. Brain completely ignored that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  Track `shots` and `heat` separately, and assign:

```
heat = round((shots * 100) / (shots + 100));
```

You'll need to tweak it to get the exact behavior you want, I'm sure, possibly with methods like:

```
heat = min(round((shots * 110) / (shots + 110)), 100);
```

but the basic curve should be pretty close to what you want.

For cooldown, decrement `shots` at some rate (I suggest trying 1 per 300 ms and tweaking from there) and recalculate `heat` as above.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the cooldown portion at all.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch: Okay, addressed.